# How do I wait for a pthread condition variable or a signal?

Tags: c, pthreads, signals, posix

I want to wait for a pthread condition variable, but when I get a SIGUSR1 (or any other signal) I want to stop waiting and detect that it stopped waiting because of a signal, not because of a pthread_cond_signal or spurious wakeup. How can I do this?

Comment: @alk The man page for pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_timedwait says "These functions shall not return an error code of [EINTR]."

Comment: It looks like you might need to use a helper thread (for catching the signal, or waiting on the condition variable). Actually, to close all races, you might have to use two helper threads and a semaphore, with the original thread waiting on the semaphore.

Answer (score 1):

A reliable way to handle signals in a pthreads program is to mask all the signals you wish to handle in every thread, and create a dedicated signal handling thread that loops around calling `sigwaitinfo()` (or `sigtimedwait()`).

The signal handling thread can then use ordinary mutex-protected shared variables and `pthread_cond_signal()` / `pthread_cond_broadcast()` wakeups to inform other threads about the signals received.

In your example, the dedicated signal handling thread could set a (mutex-protected) flag indicating that `SIGUSR1` has been received, then signal the condition variable that your thread is waiting on.  The waiting thread just needs to check the signal flags in addition to its other shared state in the loop around `pthread_cond_wait()`.

Comment: The thread could be potentially be waiting on any condition variable in the program, so I can't just signal the condition variable the thread is waiting on from the signal handler. I could use a wrapper function around pthread_cond_wait that saves the condition in a thread-local for the signal handler, but that's hard to protect against race conditions, e.g. if the signal arrives and the handler runs pthread_cond_broadcast between storing the thread local and starting the wait.

Comment: @tbodt: POSIX says [`pthread_cond_signal()` is unsafe in a signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html) anyway.

Comment: It should always be clear which condition variables your threads could be waiting on.  If there are several possibilities, you can signal them all (condition variables can wake up spuriously anyway, so it's always safe to signal them unnecessarily).  (Also, the idea here is not to call `pthread_cond_broadcast()` from a signal handler, but from a signal-handling-thread that is running in ordinary thread context, after `sigwaitinfo()` has returned and dequeued a signal).